# Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE'

Tags: php, pdo

Использую php 7.2, модуль pdo_mysql включен

Вот что выдаёт php -m

```
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
pspell
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Не пойму что именно не так

Comment: А где выдает ошибку? *Тоже* в командной строке?

Comment: Не, ошибка при выполнении скрипта php.. например var_dump(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

Comment: ну вот при выполнении скрпита и надо смотреть phpinfo()

Comment: Вижу что используется mysqlnd...на офф сайте сказано что Эта константа не поддерживается при компиляции вместе с mysqlnd  ....Может знаете что использовать вместо неё?

Comment: Вам придётся использовать [другой драйвер](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424343/undefined-class-constant-mysql-attr-init-command-with-pdo)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov это не вариант. libmysql - это не "другой драйвер", а уже много лет не поддерживаемая библиотека.И если даже удастся сейчас наковырять её из навоза и палок, то все равно все сломается в следующей версии РНР

Comment: @Ипатьев я написал это по отношению к mysqlnd, в ссылке написано в комментарии что определение константы может исчезнуть при использовании этого расширения. “But it seems there is a bug in PHP 5.3, that causes this constant to not exists anymore -- or, at least, not when the mysqlnd driver is used (and it's the one that's configured by default)”